# Error: One or more errors occurred. too many redirects or authentication replays

Tags: c#, cakebuild

```
Task("Clone")
.Does(() => 
{          
     GitClone(@"https://gitlab.organization.com/bold-reports/javascript.git", 
            @"C:\ServerPublishing\build", 
            "username", 
            "password",
            new GitCloneSettings{ BranchName = "development" });
    });
```

Tried to execute the above code snippet for clone the source from the GitLab
with credential access. But, I am facing the issue which is like,

> "An error occurred when executing task 'Clone'.
> Error: One or more errors occurred.
> too many redirects or authentication replays"

Anyone could help me for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For GitLabs you authenticate through username and a Personal Access Token as the password.

Are you cloning with a username and a Personal Access Token?

Personal Access Tokens are generated under Users Settings / Access Tokens, and `GitClone` needs at least scope `read_repository` (scope `write_repository` needed to push back changes).

Comment: Please find the below answer for this query

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have tried this with my personal credential. Its working fine with in a Task() cake build. If I use this same set of code inside a C# class, I could not achieve the result as well performed inside the cake Task().

```
Task("Clone")
.Does(() => 
{          
 GitClone(@"https://gitlab.organization.com/bold-reports/javascript.git", 
        @"C:\ServerPublishing\build", 
        "MyUsername", 
        "MyPassword",
        new GitCloneSettings{ BranchName = "development" });
});
```

This working fine and I can clone the repository.

If I use this same code in c# like below, In the same cake build file.

```
public static void getclone()
{     
       GitClone(@"https://gitlab.organization.com/bold-reports/javascript.git", 
        @"C:\ServerPublishing\build", 
        "username", 
        "password",
        new GitCloneSettings{ BranchName = "development" });
 }
```

I am facing the below mentioned issue.

[image]

Comment: Accessing aliases from a class is unrelated to the original question, please ask that in a new StackOverflow question. This is not a answer to your question, and shouldn't therfore be posted as one.